# Assign object in asynchronous thread?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, managed-c++

I'm using the Managed C++ and C#. I have a problem with the following code.

```
//In C++, Run on background thread (not UI Thread)
while(true)
{
    BitmapSource^ bitmapSource = CreateBitmap();
    bitmapSource->Freeze();
    CSWrapperFuntion(bitmapSource); //this is a function pointer to C#
}

//In C#, Interface Project
 void CSWrapperFuntion(Object param)
 {
    mainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
    {
        BitmapSource bitmap = (BitmapSource)param;
        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            //Use this bitmap to display on UI Control
        }
    }));
 }
```

When I assign `BitmapSource bitmap = (BitmapSource)param;` in the asynchronous thread (UI thread), is there any problem when I use this bitmap object?

In the body of BeginInvoke, maybe the Object param was out of scope, and it was GC destroy?

I don't have any idea about this scenario of C#, so I can not guess any problem will occur in the future.

Someone can show me the potential bugs in this code?

Many thanks!